# 24 VDC system and metal ground

Tags: dc, ground, robotics, shock

I've built a rubber tracked mobile robot and it has a metal chassis.
I use a 24 VDC 30 Ah battery to power a system which includes two DC motors, motor controllers, an industrial PC and some sensors.

Sometimes, not very often, it can happen that I get an electric shock when I touch the robot's frame. It is not dangerous, since it is just a 24 VDC system, but I would like to understand why this happens.

Is it static electricity? There is no wire in contact with the metal chassis.

To solve this problem, I connected the chassis to a floating wire that touches on the ground while the robot moves.

However, I would like to understand how to solve the problem. Should I have to connect the battery GND to metal chassis?

Comment: Rubber-tracked system + 24V battery power + problem goes away with trailing ground wire sounds like static electricity to me.  Unless there's some other symptom you haven't discovered yet or haven't shared, the problem is fixed as much as it can be, unless you want to switch to conductive rubber tracks ($$$).

Comment: It has nothing to do with the 24V system voltage.. The high voltage that zaps you (likely kilovolts) is created between the earth and the floating metal body, isolated by the rubber tires.

Comment: Thank you a lot, guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you feel is static electricity that builds up on the robot body, which is insulated from earth by the wheels and tyres.

It's not caused by the 24 V system so there's nothing to be gained by trying to connect a battery terminal to ground.

Some companies make conductive rubber wheels and tyres that would conduct the charge to earth before it builds up. During manufacturing, a conductive material like carbon powder is put into the wheel or tyre compound.

Otherwise, you could put a trailing wire or metal strip from the robot body to dangle on the ground. Some cars used to do this with a conductive strip so people didn't get a static shock when they got in or got out.